# Compare varchar string to produce missing items list

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a table with a column. The column stores locations using `varchar` as the datatype. The locations use the format `-2,7` `-25,30` etc. I am trying to produce a list of missing locations i.e. where we don't have any customers.

The locations go from `-30,-30` to `30,30`. I can't find a way to setup a loop to run though all the options. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to create a recursive CTE for all numbers from -30 to 30?  After you learn this, the next step will be to create CROSS JOIN, and finally LEFT JOIN it to your table. You can use LISTAGG when joining the numbers to match the denormalized way your grids are stored.

Comment: No, but I will start researching it.

Comment: Good. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all combinations.

Then match the generated against the existing combinations.

```
WITH DIGITS AS
(
   SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS val(n)
),
NUMS AS
(
    SELECT (tens.n * 10 + ones.n)-50 AS n
    FROM DIGITS ones
    CROSS JOIN DIGITS tens
),
LOCATIONS AS
(
     SELECT CONCAT(n1.n,',',n2.n) AS location, n1.n as n1, n2.n as n2
     FROM NUMS n1
     JOIN NUMS n2 ON n2.n BETWEEN -30 AND 30
     WHERE n1.n BETWEEN -30 AND 30
)
SELECT loc.location
FROM LOCATIONS loc
LEFT JOIN
(
     SELECT Client_Location, COUNT(*) Cnt
     FROM dbo.Client 
     GROUP BY Client_Location
) cl ON cl.Client_Location = loc.location
WHERE cl.Client_Location IS NULL
ORDER BY loc.n1, loc.n2
```

Comment: Thank very much for your time, I have opted for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server 2017

```
;WITH cte as (
    select -30 as n --anchor member
    UNION ALL
    select n + 1  --recursive member
    from cte
    where n < 31
)
select z.* 
    from ( 
        select CONCAT(y.n,',',x.n) as locations 
        from cte as x CROSS JOIN cte y 
    ) as z
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Client as cli ON cli.client_location = z.locations
where cli.client_location IS NULL
order by z.locations asc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a recursive CTE.  This is a slight variation of SNR's approach:

```
with cte as (
      select -30 as n --anchor member
      union all
      select n + 1  --recursive member
      from cte
      where n < 30
     )
select cte.x, cte.y,
       concat(cte_x.n, ',', cte_y.n) as missing_location
from cte cte_x cross join
     cte cte_y left join
     dbo.client c
     on c.client_location = concat(cte_x.n, ',', cte_y.n) 
where c.client_location is null;
```

Or to avoid the `concat()` twice:

```
select cte.x, cte.y, v.location as missing_location
from cte cte_x cross join
     cte cte_y cross apply
     (values (concat(cte_x.n, ',', cte_y.n))
     ) v(location) left join
     dbo.client c
     on c.client_location = v.location
where c.client_location is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.